# Wierd behavior when running executable built using clion

Tags: c++, executable, clion

i am making a game for a school project. When running the game in Clion everything works fine. But when building the game and opening the target executable no fonts for the menu is rendered and the functionality is lost (if i press enter it should start the game for example). I can only see a blue screen (which i specified in the clear-function).

Do i need to compile the executable in some specific way?

Comment: does it depend on external files that happen to be in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: This question needs more details. What libraries are you using?

Comment: @RichardHodges i'm not sure, not any fonts or textures atleast but i have a file called MakeFile in that directory and also a folder called CMakeFiles, in it i have xxxxx.o files of all my classes.

Comment: @arved i am using the SFML graphics library aswell as other basic math libraries

Comment: then compare the different Makefiles, from the IDE and from the manual build, where is the difference?

Comment: @arved thank u very much!